# conditional replacement of column values mathematica

Tags: replace, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I have a data set of 30,000 points that are in the format x,y,z,c, where x,y,z, are lat, long, and elevation respectively, and "c" is a classification in numerical form.

The full data set has seven classifications, 1-7,

I need to conditionally change the fourth column numbers for all points so as to merge the 7 classifications into 4.

Numbers 1 & 2 stay the same. 
3, 4, 5 will become 3, and 
6,7 will become 4.

ie if the fourth column value is a 2, it stays as a 2. If the fourth column value is a 5, it needs to be changed to a 3.

Example:

http://imgur.com/BEaAWTr

Both

```
StringReplace  
ReplacePart
```

Look like they should work, but I'm not sure how to make the replacement of multiple inputs with the same output number?

Answer (score 1):

```
In[1]:= olddata = {
  {1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 4}, {6, 1, 2, 5}, {1, 1, 2, 6},
  {4, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 1, 7, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 5},
  {6, 1, 2, 6}, {5, 3, 5, 7}};

In[2]:= newdata = olddata /. {
  {x_, y_, z_, 4}->{x, y, z, 3}, {x_, y_, z_, 5}->{x, y, z, 3},
  {x_, y_, z_, 6}->{x, y, z, 4}, {x_, y_, z_, 7}->{x, y, z, 4}}

Out[2]= {
  {1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 3}, {6, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 4},
  {4, 3, 5, 4}, {2, 1, 7, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3},
  {6, 1, 2, 4}, {5, 3, 5, 4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bill's data

```
data = {
  {1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 4}, {6, 1, 2, 5}, {1, 1, 2, 6},
  {4, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 1, 7, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 5},
  {6, 1, 2, 6}, {5, 3, 5, 7}};
```

now

```
data[[All, -1]] = If[(z = Quotient[#, 3]) == 0, #, z - 1 + 3] & /@ data[[All, -1]]
```

Now the data becomes

```
{{1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 3}, {6, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 4}, 
 {4, 3, 5, 4}, {2, 1, 7, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, 
 {6, 1, 2, 4}, {5, 3, 5, 4}}
```